# JDBC Driver and URL

Tags: mysql, jdbc

This is my first time using jasperserver and I want to connect to mysql databae, I have been following tutorial videos and looking at the documents but I don't understand where do you get the JDBC Driver and URL. They give the hint: Hint: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb and also Hint: org.postgresql.Driver but I still don't know where to look for it.

I have already downloaded the drivers using this website, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/sql-connection-libraries#anchor-20-drivers-relational-access and transfer sqljdbc42 and sqljdbc41 into apache tomcat/lib folder already

Can someone please guide me in doing this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You tag with MySQL, but you talk about PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server in your question. Why?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I want to connect to mysql server but because there are other different kind of server I am kind of confused with what to use under driver and url but Whome has already answered my question. And in my question, which part did I say about MS SQL or PostgreSQL, sorry still learning this part, if you are saying at the hint part, that is just an example

Comment: You are talking about PostgreSQL in your first paragraph, and linking to Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver documentation in your second paragraph. As a first step when searching, make sure you exclude results about other database systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each SQL server has a different jdbc url format.

**MySQL (and also MariaDB), driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&user=myuser&password=mypwd`

**MSSQL, driver=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver**

`jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=mydb;user=myuser;password=mypwd`

Comment: Is the port number in this case fixed? For the MySQL and can I also know the difference betwwen MSSQL and MySQL. Which do I use?

Comment: If possible, can I have the format for the URL? Because I have seen many different format and I don't know which to use, for example, jdbc:mysql://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE_NAME>

Comment: 3306 is the default port number for MySQL. Unless you have it running on a non-default port, omit it.

Comment: @Dkna You use an approriate jdbc url based on the sql server engine. So if you have MySQL(mariadb) then use mysql syntax, if you have MSSQL then use mssql syntax.

Comment: Thank you for helping everyone, it finally work :)

Comment: MariaDB has their own JDBC driver and JDBC url, it is just that (for now?) the MySQL driver also works with MariaDB.